# R plot() bg color behaviour changes within Shiny app

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have built a multi-tab Shiny app that includes a tab with data plotted using the basic plot() function.

Here is a basic version of my Shiny app with the code for an example plot.

```
    ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Example plot() within Shiny App"), 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(), 
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(type = "tab", 
                          tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput(outputId = "PLOT"))
                          )
              ), 
    fluid = TRUE, position = c("left", "right")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$PLOT <- renderPlot({
    par(bg = "gray")
    plot(rnorm(1000), type = "n")
    x <- par("usr")
    rect(x[1], x[3], x[2], x[4], col = "gray")
    points(rnorm(1000))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This gives the following result:
[image: plot within shiny app]

Everything that I have read suggests that setting par(bg="gray") should set the background color to gray, but it doesn't.  There appears to be a default color setting that sets the background color to white.

I tested the same code outside of my Shiny app, and I get the expected result.

```
    par(bg = "gray")
    plot(rnorm(1000), type = "n")
    x <- par("usr")
    rect(x[1], x[3], x[2], x[4], col = "gray")
    points(rnorm(1000))
```

This gives the expected result, as shown here:

[image: same plot produced outside of Shiny app]

What is over-riding the par(bg="gray") statement in Shiny, and how do I control the plot background color, when using Shiny?

I have also tried setting the style for the renderPlot element of the app, but that didn't work.

Many Thanks

Comment: Whey I try your code on shiny 1.0.5, the plot output looks like your expected result, not like the result you get.

Comment: It is working for me too using shiny 1.0.3

Comment: That's rather confusing as I'm also running shiny 1.0.3.

Comment: I've reinstalled R (version 3.4.1) and shiny (version 1.0.5) and installed the shiny dependencies, but nothing else.  The shiny app code is now working as expected.  I'm assuming that it was an issue with another package I had in my library (is that possible if I haven't called any other packages from the library?).  If I get the chance, I'll start adding the packages back into my library one by one and try to find out which one was causing the issue.  I'll "Answer Own Question" if I find out what was causing the conflict.

Comment: @tregnog did you ever figure out what was causing the issue? I'm having the same thing happen. I reinstalled the latest versions of everything but still no luck

Comment: Hi @jjet.  I backed up my package library and then installed only those packages that I required for my shiny app.  I haven't gone back and added the other packages that I had previously installed, so I don't know which packages might have been causing the conflict.  Have you tried rebuilding your library with just the packages required for your shiny app?

Comment: Sure did. Actually that entailed just rebuilding the shiny package because I wasn't using anything else. This is puzzling.

Comment: I think I got it: the answer lies in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/gtable.html If you use plot on a gtable it will display with gray lines in the background no matter what you do with the bg setting. However if you use grid.draw then it will display with a transparent background.